# How can I let a user fill in profile parts when registering? (Using providers)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I am trying to let a user fill in profile options when they are registering. I am using the providers that come with asp.net by default.

Example: User fills in this registration form:

```
Username

Email

Age <- This is what I have tried to add in.

Password

Confirm Password
```

I got the age to show up by doing the following.

1) Adding the following code to `Web.config`

```
  <properties>
    <add name="Word" type="String" />
    <add name="Age" type="Int32" defaultValue="0" />
  </properties>
```

2) Adding the following code to my `register.aspx` view

```
         <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => Profile.Age) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Profile.Age)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Profile.Age)%>
        </div>
```

I went to run it, I filled out the form and clicked register. I got this:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

and

> Line 127:            _provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, null, out status);

So that's what I have done, which is probably all wrong. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: First, have you tried running the offending code through a debugger to see precisely where it's timing out?

Comment: It stopped timing out when I added code for "Age" to the RegisterModel in AccountModels.cs. Now the registration works as normal but it's not adding a any profile information.

Comment: Is it enough just to type Profile.Age into the view? Do I need to include and libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something working by following this wiki I found.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1327/profile-provider-in-aspnet-mvc/

It's not great and not super beginner friendly but better than anything else I found. I made the Profile model separate to the account model because it didn't explicitly state it at the start, but it still works alright.

Now I have a way to fill in the profile even if it's not at the same time as registering so I'll mark this as the correct answer.